# How to unistall xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: xcode, terminal, device

I need help to unistall xcode 4.3.2

I tried in terminal

```
sudo Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

but error, please help

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Xcode4.3, just drag the app to the trash to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 4.3 I believe (it's recent), Xcode is no longer in /Developer but is now a regular app in OS X ... so to uninstall it, just delete the /Applications/Xcode directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to uninstall an Application from Mac is that use ["Clean My Mac"](http://macpaw.com/)

Simply open Clean My Mac, Go to Uninstall Application tab and then drag and drop your application icon to it. Your application will uninstall completely from your Mac.

[image: Clean My Mac, Uninstall Applications tab]